# How do I change colors for the F# interactive shell

Tags: visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

In my current color scheme, the F# interactive shell is unreadable within Visual Studio. I've been through all the color settings, and I can't find the settings it is using.

How do you change the color settings for the F# interactive shell within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 19):

Try Tools\Options\Environment\Fonts and Colors\

Read-Only Region - background

Plain text - foreground

Comment: In VS2012 F# Interactive has it's own settings: Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> F# Interactive