# What VS.NET settings affect the theme colors for the F# interactive Window

Tags: visual-studio, f#, themes

Duplicate: [How do I change colors for the F# interactive shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316161/how-do-i-change-colors-for-the-f-interactive-shell)

Hi,

I have installed a dark theme for VS.NET which works great for everything,
except for the F# interactive Window. That window now has a black background,
the text has a white background and a light gray foreground.

I've been playing with the color options but cannot find which setting
controls the theme for the F# interactive window?

Can anybody tell me what settings affect this Window?

(Visual Studio 2008)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to Edit the **fonts and colors option** in visual studio, in the "**Text Editor**" item "**Read-Only Region**"