# How do I change colors for the F# interactive shell in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, f#-interactive

Like [How do I change colors for the F# interactive shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316161/how-do-i-change-colors-for-the-f-interactive-shell), but Visual Studio 2010 (RTM) this time.

I tried changing the "Read-Only Region" background color, restarted visual studio and the background color isn't the one I picked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a lot simpler now :-). There are a few new items for directly setting the colors used in the F# Interactive window in Visual Studio 2010 RTM.

- You can select **F# Interactive** in the **Shows settings for** drop-down on the **Fonts and Colors** tab in the Options dialog (*When you open the dialog, he selected item in the drop-down is **TextEditor** and for most of the things, you don't need other items, so this is a bit tricky to find*).
- There you can change background color of **Plain Text** to change the color  of the window (and there are a few other things that you can change too).